# Is it normal that form is stuttering when moving it while a task is running on code side?

Tags: c#, winforms, for-loop, task

I am working on Genetic Algorithyms and I have used a `for` loop to create childs.The `for` loop iterates 10 million times and I used it like this.

```
public void Start()
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                createRandomPopulation();
                while (produced < 10000000)
                {
                    int[] nums = tourSelection();
                    T mother = population[nums[0]];
                    T father = population[nums[1]];

                    X[][] gens = CrossingOver<X>.TwoPointCO(mother.Genes, father.Genes);
                    T child1 = new T();
                    T child2 = new T();

                    if (rnd.Next(1, 101) <= habitat.MutationOdd)
                    {
                        Mutation<X>.SimpleMutation(gens[0]);
                        Mutation<X>.SimpleMutation(gens[1]);
                    }

                    child1.Genes = gens[0];

                    child2.Genes = gens[1];

                    testFitness(child1);
                    testFitness(child2);

                    population[nums[nums.Length - 1]] = child1;
                    population[nums[nums.Length - 2]] = child2;

                    produced += 2;
                    double temp = double.Parse((produced * 100 / 10000000).ToString("0.00"));
                    progress = temp;
                    asyncOperation.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(delegate
                    {
                        if (ProgressChanged != null)
                            ProgressChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                    }), null);
                }
            });
        }
        void createRandomPopulation()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < habitat.MaxPopulationNumber; i++)
            {
                T desc = new T();

                if (!habitat.Repeat)
                {
                    List<X> tempGenes = new List<X>(genes);
                    desc.Genes = new X[genes.Length];
                    for (int j = 0; j < habitat.Length; j++)
                    {
                        int k = rnd.Next(0, tempGenes.Count);
                        desc.Genes[j] = tempGenes[k];
                        tempGenes.RemoveAt(k);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < habitat.Length; j++)
                    {
                        desc.Genes[j] = genes[rnd.Next(0, genes.Length)];
                    }
                }
                population[i] = desc;
                produced++;
                double temp = double.Parse((produced * 100 / 10000000).ToString("0.00"));
                progress = temp;
                asyncOperation.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(delegate
                {
                    if (ProgressChanged != null)
                        ProgressChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                }), null);
                testFitness(population[i]);
            }
        }
```

But while this code is running, the application UI responses late and is stuttering. If I add `Application.DoEvents()` inside for loop the problem is gone. I was expecting that using `Task` prevent such problems to occur, so this is unexpected for me. How can I fix this issue in a good way?

Comment: are you running it as async ?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad , the code above is inside method named `Start()` and I am just calling it in button's `Click` event.

Comment: So does that happen with *exactly* the code you posted there? If not, can you post a  Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example?

Comment: @MatthewWatson , I am not sure but to understand the code I think I must add whole code and it is too long too add. In anyway I have added some code that are doing main job in my application. I hope it works.

Comment: Ah now then, that `asyncOperation.Post()` looks mighty suspicious. I suspect that will be posting into the message queue. If true, the application would be busy handling those messages on the UI thread, which could be what is causing the stuttering. Try commenting that bit out, and if that works, see if there's a way to post progress messages less frequently.

Comment: @MatthewWatson , I used `AsyncOperation` class in a download manager application to post progress before but I didn't have a problem with it. But it might show different behaviours in different apps.

Answer (score 1):

It is not normal. There are 2 possible reasons I see here:

- Significant CPU overload. You may do well to move the running threads to a lower priority in the task (store the old priority, then reset it to this when the task is finished).
- Something in the code is going back to the UI thread, causing a lot of stress there. This would be in the code you do not show us.

Comment: Agreed - I suspect something is wrong in the code we're not being shown.

Answer (score 0):

You are posting too much progress change notifications to the UI thread.

In order to fix that in a good way, you can apply several optimizations. But let first extract the progress updating code into a separate method (which is good anyway since you have 2 places using that logic):

```
private void UpdateProgress()
{
    double temp = double.Parse((produced * 100 / 10000000).ToString("0.00"));
    progress = temp;
    asyncOperation.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(delegate
    {
        if (ProgressChanged != null)
            ProgressChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }), null);
}
```

I see three possible optimizations of skipping the `Post` call.

(1) When `progress == temp`
(2) When `ProgressChanged == null`
(3) When `Post` has been called, but not yet processed.

First two are obvious and easy to be implemented. The third one requires additional state - flag and thread synchronization.

Here is one possible implementation:

```
private object updateProgressLock = new object();
private bool updateProgressRequest = false;

private void UpdateProgress()
{
    double temp = double.Parse((produced * 100 / 10000000).ToString("0.00"));
    if (progress == temp) return; // (1)
    progress = temp;
    if (ProgressChanged == null) return; // (2)
    lock (updateRequestLock)
    {
        if (updateRequest) return; // (3)
        asyncOperation.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(delegate
        {
            lock (updateRequestLock)
                updateRequest = false; 
            if (ProgressChanged != null)
                ProgressChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }), null);
        updateRequest = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You are probably not calling that part of code in async way but you havent showed enough code to poibt a finger to prticular line where the problem is.

this article might help you: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html

edit:
i have seen your edit...

your event handler should be decorated with 'async'. it should als call await Start(). and the last, your start() method should return task (from return task.run() )

```
public async Task Start()
{
return await Task.Run()...
}
```

Comment: He doesn't need to use `async` in order for `Task.Run()` to create a background thread. It should work just fine as it is.

Comment: @MatthewWatson is right. I have tried it and not solved the problem

Comment: its not about creating task but about awaiting. you can have task run and have .Result (explicitly or implicitly) and still have ui blocked although new task was created.

Comment: did you decorate your click handler as async? did you call your Start() method with await?